# SQL literal escape character

Tags: sql, sql-server, escaping, literals

What is the escape character for MS-SQL-Server

```
WHERE field1 LIKE 'I'm'
```

Note the middle quotation is invalid, what is SQL's literal character, like / in C#

Comment: use backslash to escape it

Comment: \ Does not escape it for me, but the '' does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double `'` to escape it in SQL-Server

```
WHERE field1 LIKE 'I''m'
```

In other DB engines like MySQL using backslash works too

```
WHERE field1 LIKE 'I\'m'
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/41340)

Comment: That seems strange since it works in the Fiddle demo. What DB engine do you use?